# Dealing with flexbox and container shrinking to the width of contents

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I keep the container at the width that I specified so that it doesn’t shrink to the width of its flex items?

I noticed taking the class “flex-center” out effectively has the container keeps its width, but the elements are not centered

— I managed to do a work around by removing “flex-center”, changing the display of “.subscribe” to block and centering it with auto margin, but is there a way that I can keep all of these elements in flex?

Example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/krv9z0co/6/

```css
.flex-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.subscribe {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.s__text {
  text-align: center;
}

.subscribe__input,
.subscribe__button {
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-center">
  <div class="subscribe container">
    <div class="sub__head">
      <h3 class="s__text">Subscribe</h3>
      <p class="s__text">Be the first to know about the new templates.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sub__move">
      <input type="text" class="subscribe__input sub__block" placeholder="Your Email">
      <input type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE" class="subscribe__button">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A flex item's default `flex-shrink` value is `1`. That means it is set to *shrink to fit* its parent.

If you add `flex-shrink: 0;` to the `container` it will keep its width.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krv9z0co/8/)

Stack snippet

```css
.flex-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  flex-shrink: 0;                  /*  added  */
}

.subscribe {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.s__text {
  text-align: center;
}

.subscribe__input,
.subscribe__button {
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-center">
  <div class="subscribe container">
    <div class="sub__head">
      <h3 class="s__text">Subscribe</h3>
      <p class="s__text">Be the first to know about the new templates.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sub__move">
      <input type="text" class="subscribe__input sub__block" placeholder="Your Email">
      <input type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE" class="subscribe__button">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

Updated based on a comment.

A flex row item differs from a normal `div` when it comes to fill its parent's width, where it acts more like an `inline-block` and adjust to its content.

So if you want the `container` to act more like a `block` element (try to fill its parent's width), also add `flex-grow: 1` to it.

[Updated fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/krv9z0co/10/)

Stack snippet 2

```css
.flex-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  flex-shrink: 0;                  /*  added  */
  flex-grow: 1;                    /*  added  */
}

.subscribe {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.s__text {
  text-align: center;
}

.sub__move {                       /*  keep this if to center input/button  */
   text-align: center;
}

.subscribe__input,
.subscribe__button {
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-center">
  <div class="subscribe container">
    <div class="sub__head">
      <h3 class="s__text">Subscribe</h3>
      <p class="s__text">Be the first to know about the new templates.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sub__move">
      <input type="text" class="subscribe__input sub__block" placeholder="Your Email">
      <input type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE" class="subscribe__button">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

Update 2 based on a comment.

If you also want the content to start wrap, as it does when using `display: block`, you need to allow the flex item to shrink again, and simply remove `flex-shrink: 0`.

[Updated fiddle 3](https://jsfiddle.net/krv9z0co/11/)

Stack snippet 3

```css
.flex-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  flex-grow: 1;                    /*  added  */
}

.subscribe {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.s__text {
  text-align: center;
}

.sub__move {                       /*  keep this if to center input/button  */
   text-align: center;
}

.subscribe__input,
.subscribe__button {
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-center">
  <div class="subscribe container">
    <div class="sub__head">
      <h3 class="s__text">Subscribe</h3>
      <p class="s__text">Be the first to know about the new templates.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sub__move">
      <input type="text" class="subscribe__input sub__block" placeholder="Your Email">
      <input type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE" class="subscribe__button">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the container seems to still keep the width of the content. I'd like the container to stay at 600px width. I've seen flex-shrink mentioned a lot in regards to similar situations. I may be overlooking something with it. Thank you!

Comment: @tkss Updated my answer a little, to better explain how Flexbox work.

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate it! This has helped me a lot, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox always apply its layout on immediate children. Remove display flex from .flex-container. And add margin: auto and text-align: center in .container class. Hope it will fix the issue.

```css
.flx-center {
    
    
}

.container{
    max-width: 600px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin: auto; 
    text-align: center;
}

.subscribe{
  display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.s__text{
  text-align: center;
}

.subscribe__input,
.subscribe__button{
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<section class="flx-center">
        <div class="subscribe container">
            <div class="sub__head">
                <h3 class="s__text">Subscribe</h3>
                <p class="s__text">Be the first to know about the new templates.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sub__move">
                <input type="text" class="subscribe__input sub__block" placeholder="Your Email">
                <input type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE" class="subscribe__button">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thank you, I eventually came to a similar conclusion, but it felt weird because keeping that same structure with flex-center and then a wrapping it with a container has worked well for the rest of my code. At least it works though!